# Laravel 5.2 Blade array is displaying as object

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a dropdown / select box. I'm using this code to obtain values (commented // lines indicates different things I've tried:

```
public static function getCategories(){
    return self::groupBy('category')->get(['category']);
    //orderBy('category','asc')->groupBy('category')->get(['category']);
    //distinct()->get(['category']); 
}
```

On my View, in the dropdown / select box I get the results in an object/entity format:

Select Category
{"category":"Testing 1"}
{"category":"Testing 2"}
{"category":"Testing 3"}
{"category":"Testing 4"}
These are all unique values as expected; however, I only want to display  the value and not object.
Reading Laravel 5.2+ documentation I see that I *should* use **pluck()**. 
 Unfortunately,I haven't found a method that works (I'm a 1-2 year old PHP noob).
This is a blog application: 
The "new blog post" form is where there is field for *category*. My client doesn't want a dropdown / select box to select their category;

***TL:DR***
I'm searching for unique values in the *category* column on the *blog* table to display in a dropdown / select box on my applications' sidebar to allow a search for posts with the category tag.

 Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Form::select() to build the widget then it expects an associative key=>value array. So your getCategories() method could be the following:

```
public static function getCategories(){
    return self::groupBy('category')->lists('category', 'category');
}
```

Comment: Well I'll be. I saw that **lists()** was going to be replaced with **pluck()** in 5.3; I must have disassociated myself. -Thank you @jakub_wrona